# Imprimir array de izquierda a derecha

Tags: java

El requisito es que debe de ser en un array char de 10 posiciones al menos esto debe cumplirse.

sé que se puede  hacer con 2 for uno para imprimir y otro para ir cogiendo las posiciones e ir insertandolo delante de su actual es decir, llevo bastante tiempo intentandolo sin exito, pues no consigo que vaya cogiendo las posiciones.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
en la iteracion 1:
m
iteracion 2:(la m debe de pasar a la posicion 1 y la posicon 0 cogera la i)
i m
iteracion 3: (la i y la m se mueven una posicion por delante y la 0 tendra ahora la r)
r i m

Esta seria la salida
                  M
                  Mi
                 Mir
               Mira
              Mira 
             Mira c
           Mira có
        Mira cóm
      Mira cómo
     Mira cómo 
     ira cómo m
    ra cómo mo
    a cómo mol
     cómo mola
```

os dejo mi código no consigo hacerlo:

```
         char []desplazado=new char[10];
    char aux;
    byte contador=8;
   byte original=9;
            String texto = "Mira como mola esto, una marquesina";
      for (int i = 0; i < desplazado.length; i++) {

          for (int j = 0; j < desplazado.length-1; j++) {
               /*0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
                                  m i
              */

           desplazado[original]=texto.charAt(j);
              if (original>0) {
                original--;  
              }
         aux=desplazado[original];
                   desplazado[contador]=aux;
                   if (contador>0) {
                       contador--;
                  } 
                  System.out.println(desplazado);
          }

 }
```

Comment: Me voy acercando...

Answer (score 3):

Mira a ver si te sirve esto. Creo que esta manera de hacerlo es más fácil que con un `array`.

```
 String frase = "Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina";

    for(int i=0;i<=frase.length();i++) {
        if(i<10) {
            System.out.println(frase.substring(0, i));
        } else{
            System.out.println(frase.substring(i-10,i));
        }
    }
```

Si necesitas hacerlo con un `array de caracteres` por algo en concreto la lógica del bucle se puede aplicar al `array` también.

Comment: Si,  necesito que sea en Char de array. Como lo aplicaría?

Comment: Up!! haber si alguien sabe hacerlo para un char [] de 10 posiciones no he conseguido hacerlo funcionar con el codigo de arriba

Answer (score 2):

Implementando lo anterior, agregando el char array, te quedaría algo como esto:

```
String frase="Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina"; 
mola(frase);

public static void mola(String frase){
    char[] marquesina = new char[10];
    String frase_temp="";
    for(int i=0;i<=frase.length();i++) {
        if(i<10) {
            frase_temp = frase.substring(0, i);
            for(int j=0; j<frase_temp.length(); j++){
                marquesina[j] = frase_temp.charAt(j);
            }
            System.out.println(marquesina);
        } else{
            frase_temp = frase.substring(i-10,i);
            for(int k=0; k<frase_temp.length(); k++){
                marquesina[k] = frase_temp.charAt(k);
            }
            System.out.println(marquesina);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes una alternativa :

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String frase = "Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina";

        for(int i=0;i<=frase.length();i++)
         {          

           System.out.println(String.format("%10s",frase.substring(i>10?i-10:0,i)));
         }
     }
}
```

**EDICION:**
Realmente es una versión resumen a la de `@miguel27`  y agrega el alineamiento hacia la derecha.

**EDICION:** Versión char array  que muestra el mismo resultado que la versión anterior.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String frase = "Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina";

        char[] chars = frase.toCharArray();
        int len=chars.length;
        for(int i=0;i<=len;i++)
        {             
             for(int j=(i>10?i-10:0);j<i;j++)
                    System.out.print(String.format((i>10 ? "%s" : (j==(i>10?i-10:0)) ? "%"+((10-i+1)>0?10-i+1:"")+"s" : "%s"),chars[j]));
              System.out.println();
        }


     }
}
```

**EDICION:** Última versión con un chat array de 10: El resultado es el mismo que los anteriores:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String frase = "Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina";

        char[] desplazador= new char[10];
        boolean izqder=false; // si es true va de izquierda a derecha, false empieza por la defechs
        int len=frase.length();
        int ini = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        { 
           for(char c : desplazador) c=' ';  // limpiamos arreglo

           if(i<10) 
          {                       
              ini=(izqder?0:10 - i -1 );     
              for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)                           
                desplazador[ini++]=frase.charAt(j);                                               
           }
           else
          {
              ini=0;
              for(int j=i-10+1;j<=i;j++)           
                desplazador[ini++]=frase.charAt(j);
           }

          System.out.println(desplazador);


        }

     }
}
```

En las tres versiones el algoritmo es el mismo, solo cambia la forma pero el concepto es el mismo.