# Tengo un problema con este código Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10

Tags: java

El Objetivo es hacer una marquesina tal que así:, en un array de 10 posiciones

```
M
        Mi
       Mir
      Mira
      Mira 
    Mira c
   Mira có
  Mira cóm
 Mira cómo
 Mira cómo 
ira cómo m
ra cómo mo
a cómo mol
 cómo mola
```

y así sucesivamente: texto="Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina!";

Éste es mi código:

```
    String txtString="Mira cómo mola esto, una marquesina!";
        
        char[] posCharacter=new char[10];
    
        int ultimo=txtString.length()-2;//almaceno la última posición
        //byte j=(byte) (posCharacter.length-1);//posición 9
        for (int i = txtString.length() -2; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            
            
            for(int j=posCharacter.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
                posCharacter[j+1] = txtString.charAt(i);
                
                System.out.println(posCharacter);//muestra todo el contenido
                //posCharacter[i] te muestra solo lo que hay en esa posición
            }
```

Sin embargo, me salta constantemente el error de OutOfBounds Exception. Por lo que tengo entenido es debido a que la longitud del texto (txtString) > que la del array, pero es que quiero que se muestre en un array de 10 posiciones, aunque no se como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: donde eh visto esto antes?...ah sii https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326040/imprimir-array-de-izquierda-a-derecha

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Imprimir array de izquierda a derecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326040/imprimir-array-de-izquierda-a-derecha)

Comment: gracias, si que responde a la pregunta